# Pig Latin translator, consonants

Tags: vb.net, string

Ok so I got a small code on trying to convert english into Pig Latin, I got the vowels working but the consonants are more difficult, based on what i have i can only remove the first consonant, 
So the word "what" is translated into "hatway" instead of "atwhway" please help, I'm still new to VB this is what i have

```
Public Const Vowels As String = "aeiou"
Public Const Consonant As String = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"
Private Const ConsonantSuffix As String = "ay"

For consonantIndex As Integer = 0 To Consonant.Length - 1 Step 1
            If word.ToLower.StartsWith(Consonant(consonantIndex).ToString) Then
                word = word.Remove(0, 1)
                word = word & Consonant(consonantIndex) & ConsonantSuffix
            End If
        Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest a different strategy. Find the index first vowel, and then rearrange the letters around that index.

```
Dim index = word.IndexOfAny(Vowels.ToArray)
If (index > 0) then
    word = word.Substring(index) & word.Remove(index)
End If
word &= ConsonantSuffix
```

You can make this slightly more efficient by storing the Vowels array statically rather than calling `ToArray` every time.

Examples (taken from the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin) on the subject):

- '`happy`' → '`appyhay`'
- '`duck`' → '`uckday`'
- '`glove`' → '`oveglay`'
- '`egg`' → '`eggay`'
- '`inbox`' → '`inboxay`'
- '`eight`' → '`eightay`'

Comment: You are a life saver!! Just tried it and it worked!!

Comment: Wait, how about with a word like "Bob" with your method it comes out like "obBay" how would you get it to be "obbay"

Comment: @OPJ Use `word.Remove(index).ToLower` instead of `word.Remove(index)`.

Comment: How would keep the orignal casing? Like "Bob" would be "Obbay" but then theres a word like "WHAT" how would i keep the casing to be "ATWHAY"

Comment: @OPJ Well there are a few issues with that. You have to first figure out if this is a title case ("Bob") or an all caps word ("WHAT") and then apply the the capitalization rules accordingly. You'll also have to tweak your vowels array to accept both upper and lower case strings. Neither of those tasks are too hard, and I'm sure you'll find good solutions on Google or here, but it's probably outside the scope of this question.

Comment: I'm sorry last question, what would type on google for this, I'm sorry, i'm brain dead at the moment for all stress on this assignment

Comment: @OPJ Well start with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448206/detecting-if-a-string-is-all-caps and then see how you can figure out how use `Char.IsUpper` to test for title case as well as all caps. Then you can search for various solution to convert the word to title case (i.e. to capitalize word). Try it out yourself. If you get stuck, you can always come back here and ask another question.