# C#: Confusion about ToUpper() and ToLower()

Tags: c#, string-comparison

if I do something like this...

```
String myVar = "in";
if(myVar.ToUpper() == "in")
{
    //do something
}
```

This is not going to go inside "if" block ..right?

or

Is it going to check BOTH for "in" AND "IN" and do whatever is there inside that if? If so, why is that ? Isn't it supposed to skip what's inside of "if" block?

Same confusion is about `ToLower()` too

**Edit**: So to check for both cases, I need to write:

```
if((myVar.ToUpper().Equals("in"))&&(myVar.Equals("in")))
```

Like this..right?

Comment: Jon's advice is solid, but I'd like to explain what went wrong above. If you want to check for it being "in" and don't care about case, you can either do `ToLower` and compare to "in" or `ToUpper` and compare to `IN`. You don't need multiple compares. In any case, I do recommend what Jon advised.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Rather than converting to upper case and then comparing, you should use an equality comparison which can be made case-insensitive. For example:

```
if (myVar.Equals("in", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
     ...
}
```

You should consider carefully exactly which rules are appropriate - ordinal, the current culture, the invariant culture, or possibly another culture entirely (e.g. using `StringComparer.Create(culture, true)`).

For more details around this, read the MSDN [Best Practices for Using Strings in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121.aspx) article.

Comment: +1 for being (so far) the only answer that mentions "culture" besides lower-case and upper-case.

Comment: For if statements I totally agree with you but what about switch statement of strings? I've read somewhere that its best to convert string to upper case e.g. switch(myVar.ToUpper()) { case "MYCASE1": ... }

Comment: @mjf196: That depends on the context - what's being upper-cased here? If it's user input, you really need to think about exactly what you want the behaviour to be.

Comment: P.S. Ordinal comparison is the fastest method for comparing strings according to MS http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc165449.aspx

Comment: @PaulZahra: Yes, but performance is almost always secondary to correctness.

Comment: I believe it's frowned upon by some but I've always liked reversing the variable and the literal as a way to skip a generally necessary-but-unnecessary null-check, as in:  if ("in".Equals(myVar, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) ...

Answer (score 5):

The expression `something.ToUpper().Equals("lowercaseletters")` will never be true, so in your example the if-block will not be executed. And of course, this applies to ToLower as well; `something.ToLower().Equals("UPPERCASE")` will never be true, either.

Answer (score 2):

"IN" is not equal to "in" - so it does not execute the if block. In the case of toLower() it would execute the if block as "in" equals "in"..

Answer (score 2):

First if you want to compare strings use .Equals()

```
myVar.toUpper().Equals("in")
```

Second first all code inside the if is executed, only after that the return is tested.

so

```
String myVar="in";
if(myVar.toUpper().Equals("in"))
{
  //do something
}
```

don't *"do something"*.

Comment: Ok, I'll bite: why use `Equals`?

Comment: Steven: fampinheiro is writing in Java apparently, where `Equals` is required because `==` is not overloaded for strings.

Comment: In some languages the “==” operator compares two object references to see whether they refer to the same instance. I do not believe this is the case in c# though; the operator calls String::Equals under the hood. It still compares the byte-by-byte values though, so you in fact probably want .Compare()

Answer (score 2):

If you do something like you said, it will not go into the if block, and here is why:

Operators are applied to the object on the left.  So your code is the same as writing this:

```
String myVar="in";
String testVar = myVar.ToUpper();
if(testVar=="in") //This will never be true
{
  //do something
}
```

In your edit, you still aren't testing if your string is == "IN", you are doing 2 tests to see if your string is  == "in".

If you changed your original to this it would work:

```
String myVar="in";
if(myVar.ToUpper()=="IN")
{
  //do something
}
```

Your edit should be like this to test both cases:

```
if((myVar.ToUpper().Equals("IN"))&&(myVar.Equals("in")))
```

EDIT: Some more explanation from Steven's Comment:

```
if((myVar.ToUpper().Equals("IN"))&&(myVar.Equals("in")))
```

That code sample does 2 comparisons, but if myVar will only ever be mixed case versions of in (IE: in In iN IN) then the second comparison is not necessary.  Once I have converted the string to ToUpper(), you only need to check if it is equal to IN.  So I would replace that line with:

```
if(myVar.ToUpper().Equals("IN"))
```

or

```
if(myVar.ToUpper() == "IN")
```

I would personally use the == not the .Equals method.

Comment: I don't see the point of doing both tests. If the second is true, the first will also be. Likewise, I don't know why you're using `Equals`. Do you?

Comment: @Steven I'm using it because that's what the OP used in his questions.  In the second situation, you are correct.  Just using it becase that is what the OP used.

Comment: Well, that explains it, but I assure you that our answers are not obligated to repeat any errors from the questions. :-)