# Linq Match same values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have Product on database.
Product name is "**WINNER**".

İf i add new product with name "**Winner**" , result is null.

How can i match **WINNER** and **Winner** as same  ?

```
public ActionResult AddProduct(MyModel model)
{

var Result = context.Product.Where(s => s.ProductName == model.NewProductName).FirstOrDefault();

return view();
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It should "just work", if `context.Product` is an `IQueryable<Product>` managed by your ORM.

Comment: @ta.speot.is Only if the database collation of `ProductName` is case insensitive. Apparently, it isn't.

Comment: @GertArnold I considered that but thought it more like that OP has done something like creating their own IContext interface with IEnumerable<T> Products.

Answer (score 2):

```
public ActionResult AddProduct(MyModel model)
{
var Result = context.Product.Where(s => s.ProductName.ToUpper() ==  model.NewProductName.ToUpper()).FirstOrDefault();
return view();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
var Result = context.Product.Where(s => s.ProductName.ToUpper() == model.NewProductName.ToUpper()).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [ToLower()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.tolower.aspx) on both product names when comparing:

```
var Result = context.Product
                    .Where(s => s.ProductName.ToLower() == model.NewProductName.ToLower()).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no method for matching case-insensitive strings in Linq-to-SQL, so you need to convert both strings to the same casing:

```
var Result = context.Product.Where(s => 
    // Make sure both sides are non-null for comparison
    s.ProductName != null && model.NewProductName != null &&
    // Convert both strings to same case
    s.ProductName.ToLower() == model.NewProductName.ToLower()).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Equals` with a `StringComparison` type:

```
var Result = context.Product.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ProductName.Equals(model.NewProductName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

I also merged the `Where()` with `FirstOrDefault()`.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371150/comparing-two-strings-ignoring-case-in-c-sharp) for more information about string comparisons.