# ToUpper Desription In Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

what it the meaning of that code

```
  if (theStatus.ToUpper() == "APPROVE")
                {
                    if (theLinkButtonDownload != null)
                    {
                        theLinkButtonDownload.Visible = true;
                    }
                }
```

in this  what to upper exactly done?

Comment: ToUpper() simply CAPITALIZED all possible capitalizable characters in the string.

Comment: Are you looking for something like "it means someone does not know how to use enums" or "I love ALL CAPS"? Or "does it have security issues"? Or something else (assuming you've clicked F1 in VS to get help on the `ToUpper` method already)

Comment: Note: a better alternative is to use a string comparison that ignores case when possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371150/comparing-two-strings-ignoring-case-in-c-sharp

Comment: Actually, @JDwyer, a better alternative would have been to consult MSDN to see what they have to say instead of asking such a simple question on SO.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.toupper(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: does not display minimal understanding

Answer (score 3):

**1.**  `.ToUpper()` returns the string in `UPPERCASE`.
 so that all letters in in your string variable `theStatus` becomes capital.

basic advantage of using  `.ToUpper()` is while comparing the string if you want to `ignore` the `case` (either `upper` or `lower`) you can `convert` the String to Capital using  `.ToUpper()` and then compare with `CAPITAL` String.

```
if (theStatus.ToUpper() == "APPROVE")
```

**2.** you can achieve same thing  by `converting` your variable `theStatus` into `Lower case` and then compare with `LowerCase Letters` using `.ToLower()` function.

```
if (theStatus.ToLower() == "approve")
```

**3.** You can do same thing using `Equals()` Method by passing `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` so that while comparing Strings `Equals` method `Ignore` the `Case` and perform `Comparision`.

Note : here you do not need to compare with either `LOWER` or `UPPER` case letters because `Equals()` just ignore the case and do the `Comparison`.

1=>  `if (theStatus.Equals("APPROVE", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))`

2=>  `if (theStatus.Equals("approve", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))`

3=>  `if (theStatus.Equals("aPpRoVe", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))`

all of the above cases are `true` if your `theStatus` contains `approve` in any case.

Answer (score 0):

To change the value of `theStatus` variable to be Upper Case character.

Answer (score 0):

Please see other guys' answer for what does "ToUpper()" do.

But my suggestion is to define the status in a const variable, and use this variable whenever you set or get the value. So you don't need to care about it's upper or lower case and it's more maintainable.

```
public class MyStatus
{
        public const string Approve = "Approve";
        public const string Deny = "Deny";
}

//...
if (theStatus == MyStatus.Approve) {...}
```