# Ignoring case in Linq.Any, C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have code that ignores common words from user input:

```
string[] ignored_words = { "the", "and", "I" };

String[] words = UserInput.Split(' ');
foreach (string word in words)
{
    if (!ignored_words.Any(word.Equals))
    {
        // perform actions on desired words only
    }
}
```

This works great, unless the case is wrong *("THE" as user input will not be caught by the "the" ignored word)*.

How can I add an [IgnoreCase clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371150/comparing-two-strings-ignoring-case-in-c-sharp) to the Equals comparison?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
if (!ignored_words.Any(w => w.Equals(word, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)))
{
   // ...
}
```

or with the static [`String.Equals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hkt4325(v=vs.110).aspx) which has no issues with `null` values:

```
if (!ignored_words.Any(w => string.Equals(w, word, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)))
{
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to pass a lambda expression:

```
ignored_words.Any(w => word.Equals(w, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

However, you can make your code much simpler and faster by using more LINQ:

```
foreach (string word in words.Except(ignored_words, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

Answer (score 6):

As a more efficient way of doing it:

```
// note: the exact comparer deserves some thought; cultural? ordinal? invariant?
var ignored_words = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
{
    "the", "and", "I"
};

foreach (string word in words)
{
    if (!ignored_words.Contains(word))
    {
        // perform actions on desired words only
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually tried using Contains, but it picked up ignored words within words. For instance, breathe would be ignored because it contained 'the'.

Comment: @TravisHeeter no, that isn't the same `Contains`; what you are describing is `string.Contains`; I am using `HashSet<string>.Contains` - it works completely differently: it would work correctly