# How to check user input case insensitive

Tags: c#

I have to find the square of a number / 12345 / - it's done. I wanted to make the program a bit more complicated and I have this:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The square of the number 12345 is");
        Console.WriteLine(Math.Sqrt(12345));
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number to calculate the square:");
        int numVal = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("The square of your number is" + " " + Math.Sqrt(numVal));
        Console.WriteLine("Do you wish to enter another number? Yes / No");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (input == "Yes")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a number to calculate the square:");
                int newNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("The square of your number is" + " " + Math.Sqrt(newNum));
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Have a nice day!");
            }

    }
}
```

Now a have this problem: when the program asks if I want to enter another number, the answer should be with capital letter / Yes, No /. Is there a way to make it work even if I enter the answear with lower case / yes, no /?

Comment: Do you want the square or the square root?  [Math.Sqrt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.sqrt(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Try with `OrdinalIgnoreCase` in `IndexOf` method instead of comparing `==` operator.

Comment: Try 

input.toLowerCase == "yes"

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371150/comparing-two-strings-ignoring-case-in-c-sharp

Comment: `if(input.StartsWith("Y", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))`

Comment: The title does not describe the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a C# case insensitive equals operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631233/is-there-a-c-sharp-case-insensitive-equals-operator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your input, below line will react.

```
if(string.Equals(input, "Yes", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
{
  // Your stuffs
}
```

or

```
if(string.Equals(input, "Yes", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
  // Your stuffs
}
```

**Note:** OrdinalIgnoreCase compares the character codes without cultural aspects. This is good for exact comparisons, like login names, but not for sorting strings with unusual characters like é or ö. This is also faster because there are no extra rules to apply before comparing.

For more info : [Go Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.ordinalignorecase(v=vs.110).aspx) or [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/stringcomparison)

Comment: I wouldn't suggest Ordinal (better Invariant if English string is hardcoded and always CurrentCulture if it may be localized) but not doubt **this is the only right answer**.

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
...
string input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (input.ToUpper() == "YES")
            {
                ...
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked just fine and I learned something new. I allways search for the fastest and easiest way to make my program work. :)

Comment: I will keep that in mind, thank you very much, Adriano!

Comment: @NitinSawant, sorry I cant really understand your comment. ..My answer is straight forward and answers the Q directly...

Comment: @apomene _problem_ of `ToUpper()` comparison is that it isn't _locale-safe_. It's perfectly OK for an en-US toy example, OP is satisfied and his code works. However it'll fail in real world if your application is internationalized. Discussion about this issue can be incredibly long but just imagine you have a command `"include"`. Now imagine you deploy your application in a Turkish locale. You'll see that `"include".ToUpper() == "INCLUDE"` will fail. Turkish example is somehow _typical_, if you have time you may have fun reading [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27229590/1207195).

Answer (score -2):

```
string.Equals(input, "Yes", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Comment: Using ordinal comparison (instead of CurrentCulture or InvariantCulture, depends on context) you vanish half of the benefits of String.Equals() and it's no better than a naive ToUpper().