# Best way to compare two strings ignoring case

Tags: c#, string

I want to compare two stings case insensitive but I'm not sure about the best way to do it. The strings have a average length of 20 and this question is more about state of the art and not about best performance

Most of my code uses

```
bool output = "foo".ToLower() == "FOO".ToLower();
```

which seems a bit old fashioned to me. Another way I've seen many times is

```
bool output = Regex.IsMatch("foo", "FOO", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

I guess that's possible but RegEx is not made for such simple things.

After that 3 "good" way are left:

```
bool output = string.Compare("foo", "FOO", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) == 0;
bool output = string.Compare("foo", "FOO", true) == 0;
bool output = "foo".Equals("FOO", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: This is an opinion based question. But in my opinion: `string.Equals("x", "y", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

Comment: Source IndexOf not an option?

Comment: Also look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121957/how-can-i-do-a-case-insensitive-string-comparison) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371150/comparing-two-strings-ignoring-case-in-c-sharp)

Comment: what do you mean, "the best"? best performance-wise, shortest, most readable?

Comment: @NikaGamkrelidze it's all sayed in the 2nd sentence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a look at the corresponding reference sources

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,bda3b2c94b5251ce

```
    public static int Compare(String strA, String strB, bool ignoreCase)
    {
        if (ignoreCase) {
            return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.Compare(strA, strB, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase);
        }
        return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.Compare(strA, strB, CompareOptions.None);
    }
```

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,0be9474bc8e160b6

```
    public static int Compare(String strA, String strB, StringComparison comparisonType) 
    {
    ... 
        // Agrument validation, reference equality, null test

        switch (comparisonType) {
        ...
           case StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase:
                return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.Compare(strA, strB, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,d47c1f57ad1e1e6e

```
    public static bool Equals(String a, String b, StringComparison comparisonType) {
    ... 
       // Agrument validation, reference equality, null test

       switch (comparisonType) {
        ...
           case StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase:
                return (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.Compare(a, b, CompareOptions.None) == 0);
```

you'll find these three methods being *equal* one another. As for other ways, `Regex.IsMatch` is definitely an *overshoot* (all you have to do is to compare strings); `ToLower()` can be tricky when dealing with culture specific letters, see

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I

that's why a better design is to declare your intends *clearly* (= I want to compare strings) then mask them (and let the system decieve you)

Answer (score 1):

If you're checking for equality, use `Equals`. Using `Compare` is equaivalent to, say, using

```
if (collection.Count() == 0)
```

instead of

```
if (collection.Any())
```

in LINQ. Even if it the two may currently be implemented and perform similarly, you're masking your intent and you've got no *guarantee* of that being the case in future.

Comment: but `Compare` does also determine a sorting order (-1,0,1) and `Equals` is only about checking equality right?

Comment: Exactly. If you are concerned about whether two items are equal, you should be calling the method that checks whether they are equal, not the one that checks whether one is bigger or smaller than the other.

Answer (score -2):

i think it is good

```
bool output = Regex.IsMatch("foo", "FOO", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: I think regex is the last thing you should ever consider, it's only good when all else fails. Which shows that this question is opinion-based and thus off-topic here