# How to compare two strings and their upper and lower case signs

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio-2010

Let's say I have 2 strings. First string is `x = "abc"` and the second one is `y = "ABC"`. In C# when I write the following code:

```
if (x == y)
```

or

```
if (x.Equals(y))
```

the return value is `true`. How can I check their upper and lower case?

Comment: Here's some more info on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring

Comment: Do you mean if  `x = "abc"` and `y = "ABC"`, then `(x == y)` should return **false**??

Comment: yes.I want to check case sensitivity.

Comment: But `(x == y)` will always return **False** if `x = "abc"` and y = `"ABC"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C#: Confusion about ToUpper() and ToLower()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694863/c-confusion-about-toupper-and-tolower)

Answer (score 32):

The return value is *not* `true` but `false` since .NET is case sensitive by default.

From [`String.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/858x0yyx.aspx):

> This method performs an ordinal (**case-sensitive** and
>   culture-insensitive) comparison.

For `==` the same is true since [`String.Equality` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.op_equality.aspx) calls `Equals`:

> This operator is implemented using the **Equals** method, which means the
>   comparands are tested for a combination of reference and value
>   equality. This operator performs an **ordinal comparison.**

This will compare case insensitively:

```
bool equals = x.Equals(y , StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

If you just want to know if a character is upper or lower case you can use these methods:

```
bool isUpperChar = Char.IsUpper("ABC"[0]); // yes
bool isLowerChar = Char.IsLower("ABC"[0]); // no
```

Answer (score 8):

First, you should decide whether you compare strings in `culture dependent` or *independent* way (e.g. in Russian Culture letters "E" and "Ё" often treats as being the same; Finnish tends to treat "V" and "W" as being the same etc.). Next you should choose whether use or not use *case* ("a" v. "A"). So there're 6 possible comparisons:

**Ordinal** (*culture independent*) comparisons:

```
// Ignore case comparison
Boolean equals = String.Equals(x, y, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
// Case comparison
Boolean equals = String.Equals(x, y, StringComparison.Ordinal);
```

**Current culture** comparisons:

```
// Current culture, ignore case comparison
Boolean equals = String.Equals(x, y, StringComparison.CurrentCulture);
// Current culture, case comparison
Boolean equals = String.Equals(x, y, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

**Explicit culture** comparisons:

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("Ru-ru"); // <- Or whatever you want

// Explicit culture, ignore case comparison
Boolean equals = culture.CompareInfo.Compare(x, y, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase);
// Explicit culture, case comparison
Boolean equals = culture.CompareInfo.Compare(x, y, CompareOptions.None);
```

Comment: compare method return c like int. not bool an if statement should look like below:
if (culture.CompareInfo.Compare(PaymentReq.IslemTipi, "ödeme", CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) == 0)

Answer (score 2):

As Pleun wrote, or you can

```
StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase.Equals(a, b)
```

Note that we are using the `CurrentCulture` ordering method. Sometimes you'll have to use different ordering methods (every language orders the letters in a different way)

If you are sure that you are only ordering ASCII characters then

```
StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(a, b)
```

is a little faster (or in general methods where you can select the `OrdinalIgnoreCase`)

In general converting `ToUpper()` or `ToLower()` two strings to compare them is **wrong** (and slow, because you have to convert them fully before comparing them, while perhaps they are different in the first character)... Wrong because in Turkish there are four `i`

http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail/

Answer (score 1):

Try:

Case sensitive:

```
String.Equals (a,b)
```

Case Insensitive

```
string.Equals(a, b, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another option you can try.

```
if(string.Compare("a", "A", true) == 0)
```