# Where is uppercase/lowercase conversion method for StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, string, globalization

In the simple method below, for string comparers  I'm calling corresponding `ToLower()` methods. **Is there case conversion method for `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` exposed somewhere in the framework?**

```vb
Function ToLowerIfCaseInsensitiveComparison(s As String, cmp As StringComparison) As String
    Select Case cmp
        Case StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase
            Return s.ToLower()
        Case StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase
            Return s.ToLowerInvariant()
        Case StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase
            Return ___________________ ' expecting your answers
        Case Else
            Return s
    End Select
End Function
```

(C# or VB – whatever you prefer. The answer probably won't be language-dependent anyway.)

---

**UPDATE:** I have to correct myself regarding lowercase conversion: [Best Practices for Using Strings in the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd465121.aspx) says that

> Use the **String.ToUpperInvariant** method instead of the **String.ToLowerInvariant** method when you normalize strings for comparison.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640).

Comment: Also you might find [Upper vs Lower Case](http://stackoverflow.com/q/234591/11683) and [C#: Confusion about ToUpper() and ToLower()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3694863/11683) useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase can be used as a parameter for string.Equals, to save you have to using ToLower to remove case sensitivity in your comparison.

In C#:

```
var string1 = "Hello";
var string2 = "hello";

Console.WriteLine(string1.Equals(string2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

// Output: true
```

An Ordinal comparison is based on the numeric value (Unicode code point) of each Char in the string.
If you want to return the string in a format for ordinal comparison you could use this method:

```
string GetUnicodeString(string s)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (char c in s)
    {
        sb.Append("\\u");
        sb.Append(String.Format("{0:x4}", (int)c));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I prefer `string.Compare` - for clarity and for added benefit of being able to compare `null` strings.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Compare. That could come in useful

Comment: @miroxlav I don't understand what you mean

Comment: @GSerg – `String.Equals()` is recommended for *comparison* while `String.Compare()` is recommended for *sorting* – see [Best Practices for Using Strings in the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd465121.aspx). They seem to explicitly discourage using the latter for string comparison, I quote: *Do not use an overload of the **String.Compare** or **CompareTo** method and test for a return value of zero to determine whether two strings are equal.*

Comment: @miroxlav Okay, that notice seems to have appeared for .NET 4.0 and up. I was not aware of it, and I now wonder why it exists and why it makes a difference.

Comment: @GSerg – they use different default comparison. `string.Equals()` (equivalent to `==` in case of strings) uses *Ordinal* (binary) comparison, while `string.CompareTo()` uses *CurrentCulture*. Although that article recommends *always* providing the comparison *explicitly*, if you use implicit one, then *Ordinal* (binary) comparison would be probably expected by most developers who want to determine whether strings are *equal*. Thus this speaks against `string.CompareTo()` and in favor of `string.Equals()`.

Comment: @miroxlav I never use implicit ones, so I really wonder why `if (string.Compare(s1, s2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)` is bad and `if (s1.Equals(s2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))` is not. In my opinion the former is better because it won't explode when `s1` is `null`.

Comment: @GSerg – I wonder why odd&obsolete C-language practice has a place in .NET (except of reason that you set some custom standards for your project...) but that's different topic and I do not want to make long discussions here. Of course, if you are not having `null`s under control, then I understand that you need to apply a workaround. In your shoes, I would add extension method for Equals, handling nulls gracefully.

Comment: It's just sometimes people who write content for MSDN make mistakes, so one has to be aware. [static int Compare](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/0be9474bc8e160b6.html) has the same internals as [public bool Equals](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/b98069ccbe2d3960.html), and is referenced thousands of times from the internals of .NET framework in the form of `if (string.Compare() == 0)`.

Comment: The only difference is that for the `Ordinal` comparison, `Compare` calls [CompareOrdinalHelper](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/8711fff131bc4d0e.html) and `Equals` calls [EqualsHelper](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/11648d2d83718c5e.html), and the latter appears to be a tiny fraction faster in its `unsafe` code because it does not have to tell if the first string is greater or less than the second, only that they are equal or not.