# if string value is used in case then we not need to convert there format before comparison?

Tags: c#

I have used below code in a project and someone ask me to use `ToLower()` or `ToUpper()` and I think it is unnecessary.

```cs
public somefun(Classabc clsabc, string emptype, string id)
{
    switch(emptype)
    {
        case :"AnyInput":
            {
            //do 
            }
            break;
        case :"StringInput":
            {
            //do 
            }
            break;
    }
}

if(emptype=="AnyInput")
{
    ///
}
```

Is the above perfect or we need to use `ToLower()` or `ToUpper()` with `empType` in `if()`? Is there any issue or programming rule violation with my code? According to me in `case` (`switch`) we are using email type as constant for case matching and if `emptype` value can be used in case matching then there is no need to add extra functions to convert to there case before string matching.

Comment: `switch(emptype)` will only do a case sensitive match, same as `==`. For a case-insensitive match, use `string.Equals(..., StringCompairson.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

Comment: Hi Charlieface,here can i say emptype is working as constant string in switch case?

Comment: `Is the above perfect` - no. It won't compile, it is not valid C#. The suggestion to use ToLower or ToUpper is [not correct either](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3694903/11683).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you guys are looking for.

If the comparison is case sensitive, you can keep the switch-case comparison like you did in the example you provided.

In case the comparison is insensitive, you can pattern matching (C# 7 and above) and write something like this:

```
switch (true)
{
    case bool b when emptype.Equals("AnyInput", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase): 
        // do
        break;
    case bool b when emptype.Equals("StringInput", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase): 
        // do
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```