# Case insensitive std::string.find()

Tags: c++, string, stl, case-insensitive, wstring

I am using `std::string`'s `find()` method to test if a string is a substring of another. Now I need case insensitive version of the same thing. For string comparison I can always turn to `stricmp()` but there doesn't seem to be a `stristr()`.

I have found various answers and most suggest using `Boost` which is not an option in my case.  Additionally, I need to support `std::wstring`/`wchar_t`. Any ideas?

Comment: There's a Gotw about this very subject : http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/029.htm

Comment: stristr is not there, but "char *strcasestr(const char *haystack, const char *needle);" is there. Isnt this ok?

Comment: @Nasir, `strcasestr` is not available under Windows.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You could use [`std::search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search) with a custom predicate.

```
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

// templated version of my_equal so it could work with both char and wchar_t
template<typename charT>
struct my_equal {
    my_equal( const std::locale& loc ) : loc_(loc) {}
    bool operator()(charT ch1, charT ch2) {
        return std::toupper(ch1, loc_) == std::toupper(ch2, loc_);
    }
private:
    const std::locale& loc_;
};

// find substring (case insensitive)
template<typename T>
int ci_find_substr( const T& str1, const T& str2, const std::locale& loc = std::locale() )
{
    typename T::const_iterator it = std::search( str1.begin(), str1.end(), 
        str2.begin(), str2.end(), my_equal<typename T::value_type>(loc) );
    if ( it != str1.end() ) return it - str1.begin();
    else return -1; // not found
}

int main(int arc, char *argv[]) 
{
    // string test
    std::string str1 = "FIRST HELLO";
    std::string str2 = "hello";
    int f1 = ci_find_substr( str1, str2 );

    // wstring test
    std::wstring wstr1 = L"ОПЯТЬ ПРИВЕТ";
    std::wstring wstr2 = L"привет";
    int f2 = ci_find_substr( wstr1, wstr2 );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using templates here?

Comment: @rstackhouse, template here is for a support of different char types (`char` & `wchar_t`).

Comment: Thanks, Kirill. For those as clueless as I am, insert `std::advance( it, offset );` after the declaration of the iterator to start the search from an offset.

Comment: For those (like me) who are not familiar with templates, can you also post a standard version without templates, without locales? Just for `wstring` for example @KirillV.Lyadvinsky?

Comment: Does the call to `std::toupper` actually work for wide characters?  Wouldn't you need to call `std::towupper`?

Comment: please add `string.find_first_of or wstring.find_first_of` . implementation

Answer (score 76):

The new C++11 style:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

/// Try to find in the Haystack the Needle - ignore case
bool findStringIC(const std::string & strHaystack, const std::string & strNeedle)
{
  auto it = std::search(
    strHaystack.begin(), strHaystack.end(),
    strNeedle.begin(),   strNeedle.end(),
    [](unsigned char ch1, unsigned char ch2) { return std::toupper(ch1) == std::toupper(ch2); }
  );
  return (it != strHaystack.end() );
}
```

Explanation of the std::search can be found on [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/search/).

Comment: What if I want to find a char `c` in a string `str` using the same function. calling it using `findStringIC(str, (string)c)` doesnt work

Comment: This type of char to string cast does not work, you have to actually create the string object like `std::string(1, 'x')`

See http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af4051dd1d15972e

If you do this a lot it might worth creating a specific function that does not require creating a new object every time.

Comment: In most cases, it is preferable to use `tolower()` when doing a case insensitive search. Even Ada changed it to lowercase! There are reasons that Unicode.org probably explains somewhere but I do not know exactly why.

Comment: Upper case is better https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386042.aspx but of course not perfect. If you need Turkish, that's going to be hard http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234591/upper-vs-lower-case and http://haacked.com/archive/2012/07/05/turkish-i-problem-and-why-you-should-care.aspx/

Comment: ... did they do away with templates in C++11?  I must have missed the memo :)

Comment: No template needed in this case. For C++17 you might want to take a look at string_view instead of std::string https://skebanga.github.io/string-view/

Comment: That was a great read on `string_view`! Something new and shiny, and _fast_! :)

Comment: Absolute bananas that I have to write my own function for this in C++. Why isn't this kind of stuff part of standard library? It very much is in C#, Java and Python. And C++ is out there, right there together with those 3 titans.

Answer (score 21):

why not use Boost.StringAlgo:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string/find.hpp>

bool Foo()
{
   //case insensitive find

   std::string str("Hello");

   boost::iterator_range<std::string::const_iterator> rng;

   rng = boost::ifind_first(str, std::string("EL"));

   return rng;
}
```

Comment: Typically, unless a C++ question is tagged for Boost, it's assumed Boost isn't an option.

Answer (score 20):

Why not just convert both strings to lowercase before you call `find()`?

[tolower](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/tolower/)

Notice:

- Inefficient for long strings.
- Beware of [internationalization issues](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/07/05/turkish-i-problem-and-why-you-should-care.aspx/).

Comment: Because it is very inefficient for larger strings.

Comment: This is also not really a good idea if your software ever needs to be localized. See Turkey test: http://haacked.com/archive/2012/07/05/turkish-i-problem-and-why-you-should-care.aspx/

Comment: The arguments you'll uncover for doing basic upcase and downcase operations in C++ on anything not encoded as ANSI will overwhelm you xD Simply put, it's not trivial for the standard library to handle as of C++17.

Answer (score 9):

Since you're doing substring searches (std::string) and not element (character) searches, there's unfortunately no existing solution I'm aware of that's immediately accessible in the standard library to do this.

Nevertheless, it's easy enough to do: simply convert both strings to upper case (or both to lower case - I chose upper in this example).

```
std::string upper_string(const std::string& str)
{
    string upper;
    transform(str.begin(), str.end(), std::back_inserter(upper), toupper);
    return upper;
}

std::string::size_type find_str_ci(const std::string& str, const std::string& substr)
{
    return upper(str).find(upper(substr) );
}
```

This is not a fast solution (bordering into pessimization territory) but it's the only one I know of off-hand. It's also not that hard to implement your own case-insensitive substring finder if you are worried about efficiency.

> Additionally, I need to support
>   std::wstring/wchar_t. Any ideas?

tolower/toupper in locale will work on wide-strings as well, so the solution above should be just as applicable (simple change std::string to std::wstring).

[Edit] An alternative, as pointed out, is to adapt your own case-insensitive string type from basic_string by specifying your own character traits. This works if you can accept all string searches, comparisons, etc. to be case-insensitive for a given string type.

Comment: the answer i was looking for, thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want “real” comparison according to Unicode and locale rules, use [ICU’s `Collator` class](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classCollator.html).

Answer (score 1):

Also make sense to provide Boost version: This will modify original strings.

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

string str1 = "hello world!!!";
string str2 = "HELLO";
boost::algorithm::to_lower(str1)
boost::algorithm::to_lower(str2)

if (str1.find(str2) != std::string::npos)
{
    // str1 contains str2
}
```

or using perfect [boost xpression library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/xpressive.html)

```
#include <boost/xpressive/xpressive.hpp>
using namespace boost::xpressive;
....
std::string long_string( "very LonG string" );
std::string word("long");
smatch what;
sregex re = sregex::compile(word, boost::xpressive::icase);
if( regex_match( long_string, what, re ) )
{
    cout << word << " found!" << endl;
}
```

In this example you should pay attention that your search word don't have any regex special characters.

Comment: *"... I have found various answers and most suggest using Boost which is not an option in my case"*.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename charT>
struct ichar {
    operator charT() const { return toupper(x); }
    charT x;
};
template <typename charT>
static basic_string<ichar<charT> > *istring(basic_string<charT> &s) { return (basic_string<ichar<charT> > *)&s; }
template <typename charT>
static ichar<charT> *istring(const charT *s) { return (ichar<charT> *)s; }

int main()
{
    string s = "The STRING";
    wstring ws = L"The WSTRING";
    cout << istring(s)->find(istring("str")) << " " << istring(ws)->find(istring(L"wstr"))  << endl;
}
```

A little bit dirty, but short & fast.

Answer (score 0):

I love the answers from [Kiril V. Lyadvinsky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3152296/3543437) and [CC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19839371/3543437). but my problem was a little more specific than just case-insensitivity; I needed a lazy Unicode-supported command-line argument parser that could eliminate false-positives/negatives when dealing with alphanumeric string searches that could have special characters in the base string used to format alphanum keywords I was searching against, e.g., `Wolfjäger` shouldn't match `jäger` but `<jäger>` should.

It's basically just Kiril/CC's answer with extra handling for alphanumeric exact-length matches.

```
/* Undefined behavior when a non-alpha-num substring parameter is used. */
bool find_alphanum_string_CI(const std::wstring& baseString, const std::wstring& subString)
{
    /* Fail fast if the base string was smaller than what we're looking for */
    if (subString.length() > baseString.length()) 
        return false;

    auto it = std::search(
        baseString.begin(), baseString.end(), subString.begin(), subString.end(),
        [](char ch1, char ch2)
        {
            return std::toupper(ch1) == std::toupper(ch2);
        }
    );

    if(it == baseString.end())
        return false;

    size_t match_start_offset = it - baseString.begin();

    std::wstring match_start = baseString.substr(match_start_offset, std::wstring::npos);

    /* Typical special characters and whitespace to split the substring up. */
    size_t match_end_pos = match_start.find_first_of(L" ,<.>;:/?\'\"[{]}=+-_)(*&^%$#@!~`");

    /* Pass fast if the remainder of the base string where
       the match started is the same length as the substring. */
    if (match_end_pos == std::wstring::npos && match_start.length() == subString.length()) 
        return true;

    std::wstring extracted_match = match_start.substr(0, match_end_pos);

    return (extracted_match.length() == subString.length());
}
```

Comment: The last 3 lines of code should be return (extracted_match.length() == subString.length());

Comment: "should" might be a bit strong for wording, but I agree that it's an improvement! :) Ty & updated ^_^

Answer (score 0):

The Most Efficient Way

Simple and Fast.

> Performance is guaranteed to be linear, with an initialization cost of 2 * NEEDLE_LEN comparisons. (glic)

```cpp
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {

    std::string s1{"abc de fGH"};
    std::string s2{"DE"};

    auto pos = strcasestr(s1.c_str(), s2.c_str());

    if(pos != nullptr)
        std::cout << pos - s1.c_str() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strcasestr` seems to be a GNU-only extension to stdlib

Answer (score -2):

wxWidgets has a very rich string API 
[wxString](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_string.html)

it can be done with (using the case conversion way)

```
int Contains(const wxString& SpecProgramName, const wxString& str)
{
  wxString SpecProgramName_ = SpecProgramName.Upper();
  wxString str_ = str.Upper();
  int found = SpecProgramName.Find(str_);
  if (wxNOT_FOUND == found)
  {
    return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}
```