# Case insensitive find() method in string class

Tags: c++, string, find

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Case insensitive std::string.find()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152241/case-insensitive-stdstring-find)

I want to make use of the `std::string::find()` method in a case insensitive way. I have come across various solutions suggesting the Boost library, but that solution is not applicable in my scenario.

Are there other ways to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried writing some code to do this? Or don't you know where to start? It's better to post any attempts you have made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't modify the string, make a copy of it. Convert all chars to lowercase in the string and then use `find()` with a lowercase string.