# Is there a built in function for std::string in C++ to compare two strings alphabetically when either string can be uppercase or lowercase?

Tags: c++, string, case-insensitive

I know for C++ that basic comparative operators can accomplish the task if both words are either entirely lower or entirely upper case. I have an array of strings and letters can vary from lower to upper. Here is a small examle of the kind of strings I can be working with:

"ABUNDANT LIFE CH"

"NEW LIFE WMN MNSTRY"

"NEW LIFE ASSEMBLY"

I know in Java there exists the function [`String.compareToIgnoreCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)). Is there a C++ equivalent of this function?

Comment: No there is no case-insensitive comparison function in the standard library. Not even in the standard C library you could you.

Comment: Darn I feared that to be true.

Comment: Is your text restricted to ASCII?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know of any case-insensitive functions in the standard library, but you can specify a custom predicate for `std::equal`:

```
std::string a("hello");
std::string b("HELLO");
std::cout << std::equal(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(),
    [] (const char& a, const char& b)
    {
        return (std::tolower(a) == std::tolower(b));
    });
```

For a solution which takes locale into account, refer to [Case insensitive std::string.find()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3152296/3920237).

```
#include <locale>

template<typename charT = std::string::value_type>
struct my_equal {
    my_equal( const std::locale& loc ) : loc_(loc) {}
    bool operator()(charT ch1, charT ch2) {
        return std::toupper(ch1, loc_) == std::toupper(ch2, loc_);
    }
private:
    const std::locale& loc_;
};

int main()
{
    std::string a("hello");
    std::string b("HELLO");
    std::cout << std::equal(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(),
        my_equal<>(std::locale()));
}
```

Comment: That sometimes works, depending on the locale.And it works for all given examples.

Comment: @Deduplicator Could you please explain the issue? Isn't `std::tolower` locale-aware?

Comment: @sbabbi: Yes, it is. But that does not help e.g. uppercasing `ß`. There are many other examples...

Comment: Here is one of the few cases you DON'T want to pass the argument as const reference, char weights only one byte , pointer or reference weight as Integer (usually 4 bytes). not only it does not make the program faster , it makes it slower. in the first code snippet , it is better to pass the char as value

Answer (score 7):

Yes there is a case insensitive way to compare strings in C++. The key is that `std::string` is a template:

```
template <class charT,
          class traits = char_traits<charT>,
          class Allocator = allocator<charT>>
class basic_string;
```

The `traits` here control how the `charT`'s relate to each other. For normal `std::string`, they do what you'd expect, but we can just write our own traits that are case insensitive:

```
struct case_insensitive_traits
: char_traits<char>
{
    static bool eq(char a, char b) { return tolower(a) == tolower(b); }
    static bool ne(char a, char b) { return !eq(a, b); }
    static bool lt(char a, char b) { return tolower(a) < tolower(b); }
    static bool gt(char a, char b) { return tolower(a) > tolower(b); }

    static int compare(const char* a, const char* b, size_t n)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            int delta = tolower(a[i]) - tolower(b[i]);
            if (delta != 0) return delta;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    static const char* find(const char* s, size_t n, char c)
    {
        c = tolower(c);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i, ++s) {
            if (tolower(*s) == c) return s;
        }
        return nullptr;
    }
};
```

With that:

```
using case_insensitive_string = std::basic_string<char, case_insensitive_traits>;

case_insensitive_string a{"hello"};
case_insensitive_string b{"hElLo"};

assert(a == b);
```

Comment: 1+ I really like this solution it's clean and very readable and maintainable.

Comment: works only for 1-byte characters, i.e. that fits into 1 char, so it won't work for anything UTF-8.

Comment: @Benoît `charT` is also a template on `basic_string`, so you could easily extend `case_insensitive_traits` to be templated on a char type as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Boost String Algorithms:

```
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

int main() {
    std::string s { "Test" };
    assert(boost::iequals(s, "TEST"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++ usually less-than (bool less(type, type)) is used in places of tri-value function compare (int cmp(type, type)). Of course each one of them can be trivially defined in terms of the other.

Here's something that can easily be plugged into STL algorithms:

```
template<class String>
struct ciless {
  locale l_;

  explicit ciless(locale l = locale()) : l_(l) {}

  bool operator() (
      String const &a
    , String const &b) const
  {
    auto fa = a.begin();
    auto fb = b.begin();

    while (fa != a.end()
      && fb != b.end()
      && (tolower(*fa, l_) == tolower(*fb, l_)))
    {
      ++fa;
      ++fb;
    }

    return
      (fa == a.end() && fb != b.end())
      || (
          fa != a.end()
        && fb != b.end()
        && tolower(*fa, l_) < tolower(*fb, l_));
  }
};
```

And here's something that can convert less() into java-style compare():

```
template<class T, class Less = std::less<T>>
struct compare
{
  Less l_;

  explicit compare(Less l = Less()) : l_(l) {}

  int operator() (
      T const &a
    , T const &b) const
  {
    if (l_(a, b))
      return -1;

    if (l_(b, a))
      return 1;

    return 0;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing standard, but if you happen to be developing for Windows or have access to a Posix interface you could use the following:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k59z8dwe.aspx

```
// didn't run it through a compiler
// but it would look like something like this:
{
   using namespace std;
   string a = "HELLO"s;
   string b = "HelLO"s;
   bool bIsMatch = _stricmp(a.c_str(), b.c_str()) == 0;  // bIsMatch = true
}
```

Comment: Or strcasecmp on a POSIX system like Linux.

Answer (score 0):

There's a much simpler solution that doesn't involve coding loops (ugh!) or Boost:

```
string a = "Foo";
string b = "foo"

return !_stricmp(a.str(), b.str());
```

The strings are converted to char[]s, then compared, case-insensitive.  Returns true if they're equal.

(My biased opinion: C++ should provide this functionality as a string method.  Forcing millions of users to hand-code loops for such a common operation is disgusting, and introduces unnecessary "noise" into the code.)