# Understanding the std::search predicate

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to understand the s`td::search` predicate which I read about from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152241/case-insensitive-stdstring-find). I have posted it below for convenience.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

// haystack=Hello and needle=World
/// Try to find in the Haystack the Needle - ignore case
bool findStringIC(const std::string & strHaystack, const std::string & strNeedle)
{
  auto it = std::search(
    strHaystack.begin(), strHaystack.end(),
    strNeedle.begin(),   strNeedle.end(),
    [](char ch1, char ch2) { 

      std::cout << ch1 << "?" << ch2 << "\n";
    return std::toupper(ch1) == std::toupper(ch2); 
   }
  );
  return (it != strHaystack.end() );
}
```

Essentially I am confused by how it(the predicate) works. Suppose the haystack is the word `Hello` and the needle is the word `World`. Now from what I have observed is that the first letter of needle will get compared to all the letters of haystack - so `W` will get compared to `H` then `E` then `L`.... so

Comment: What crazy implementation does 25 comparisons with that?

Comment: is my understanding wrong of how this predicate is working ?

Comment: No, that's not how `std::search` works.

Comment: The predicate has absolutely nothing to do, whatsoever, with ***which*** comparisons `std::search` makes. What the predicate affects is ***how*** the comparison takes place.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik could you explain that please ? or a link

Comment: The "[Possible Implementation (Second version)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search#Possible_implementation)" section on cppreference might help clear things up for you.

Comment: "from what I have observed". On what implementation did you observe that comparison behavior with 25 comparisons?

Comment: I cant understand why this would make more than 1 comparison, after `W` != `H` the needle surely cannot be found?

Comment: So where is the "O will be compared HELLO letters consecutively"?

Comment: @NickA How so?  What if your haystack is "WHello"?

Comment: @0x5453 I mean in this exact example

Comment: @NickA.  Sure.  But my point is that `std::search` doesn't necessarily know that it can stop after the first letter, because it hasn't checked the rest of the haystack yet.  (Unless it does some extra checks like comparing string sizes.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/search/?kw=search

I included a link to some official documentation here.

The predict would return the first occurrence of the second object.

E.g. 
So comparing "Hello" to "ell" would be

```
"H" to "e" -> false
"e" to "e" -> true continue
"l" to "l" -> true continue
"l" to "l" -> true return
```