# Query a SQL Server table with multiple variables using LINQ and C# and return the results

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I want to search using multiple criteria and for every "discovery" to save to an object. I found a solution for multiple criteria [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15883516/3424327)

But how can I save every find? The example uses a `var` and probably will only find one row but what happens when you have multiple rows that match your criteria and want to save them all? Should I use `foreach`?

Comment: You'll have to store your results into a `List<something>` and return that list, if you expect more than one row to be matched

Comment: Could you point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You would need something like this

```
myvariable.Where(x => x.id == list.id && (y => y.otherfield)).Select( x => x.somethingelse));
```