# C# StringReader Class

Tags: c#, arrays, stringreader

I have this problem, I'm using StringReader to find specific words from a textbox, so far is working great, however I need to find a way how to check specific words in every line against a string array.

The following code works:

```
string txt = txtInput.Text;
string user1 = "adam";
int users = 0;
int systems = 0;

using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(txt))
{
    while ((txt = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (txt.Contains(user1))
        {
            users++;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I have created a String Array to store more than one string, but the method Contains seems to only accept a string.

```
string[] systemsarray = new string[] { "as400", "x500", "mainframe" };

if(txt.Contains(systemsarray))
{
    systems++;
}
// error message: cannot convert from string[] to string
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do this, or a way to improve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are looking for the existence of any of those words in the line, try:

```
if(systemsarray.Any(word => txt.Contains(word)))
{
    users++;
}
```

Comment: Or simply `if (systemsarray.Any(txt.Contains))`

Comment: Hard to tell for certain what the OP wants, but if they need a count, replace `Any` with `Count` and store that in `systems`.

Comment: @Moo-Juice The answer HocsanMoya selected is effectively the same as this one, only unrolled in a loop instead of as a one liner using LINQ.

Comment: Hi, I just did, I'm sorry about that.

Answer (score 5):

Why not write yourself an extension method to do this?

```
public static class StringExtensionMethods
{
    public static bool ContainsAny(this string self, params string[] toFind)
    {
        bool found = false;
        foreach(var criteria in toFind)
            {
                if (self.Contains(criteria))
                {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            };

        return found;
    }   // eo ContainsAny    
}
```

Usage:

```
string[] systemsarray = new string[] { "as400", "x500", "mainframe" };

if(txt.ContainsAny(systemsarray))
{
    systems++;
}
// error message: cannot convert from string[] to string
```

Answer (score 5):

you need to extract each item from your array:

```
foreach (string item in systemsarray)
{
 if(txt.Contains(item))
 {
    systems++;
 }
}
```

Comment: @LuameLudik, sorry to bother again, I was wondering do you know how to get rid of the duplicates? I have tried several things and still not working, I created a new String Array and tried to remove the duplicates...                          

String[] systems2 = new string[] {item};
IEnumerable<String> distinctsystem = systems2.Distinct();

foreach (String theString in distinctsystem)
{
  systems++;
 }

Answer (score 2):

If you want a case-insensitive search (`as400` will match `AS400`), you can do this

```
if (systemsarray.Any(x => x.Equals(txt, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
{
    //systemsarray contains txt or TXT or TxT etc...
}
```

You can remove [StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx) if you want to take the case into account (or choose a different enum value).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, something I did was to convert all the text to lower case; like this;     string txt = txtInput.Text.ToLower(); but I will take this in consideration, thanks again!

Comment: @HocsanMoya - You're welcome. As as side note, converting and checking the lowercase is not recommended. You should usually use the comparison check above or convert it to uppercase instead [more info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234591/upper-vs-lower-case).

Comment: Hi! Thanks, in that case, I will follow your advice.