# find index of list with params c#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, linq

I'm basically trying to convert this:

```
private int FindIndexOf(string valueOne, string valueTwo, List<string> list)
{
    return list.FindIndex(s =>
        s.ToLower().Contains(valueOne.ToLower()) &&
        s.ToLower().Contains(valueTwo.ToLower())
        );
}
```

to make use of params like this:

```
private int FindIndexOf(List<string> list, params string[] args)
{
    string pattern = String.Format("([{0}]+)", String.Join("]+[", args));
    Regex regEx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return list.FindIndex(s => regEx.IsMatch(s.ToLower()));
}
```

I'm not very good with RegEx and I can't think of a way to implement this in linq. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need regex and you don't need `ToLower`:

```
private int FindIndexOf(List<string> list, params string[] args)
{
    return list
       .FindIndex(s => args
           .All(str => s.IndexOf(str, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0));
}
```

Why `ToLower` can be incorrect: https://stackoverflow.com/a/234751/284240

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Thank you for the link on ToLower. I'll definitely stop using that in my code!

Answer (score 1):

Use All instead:

```
var argsLower = args.Select(q=> q.ToLower());
list.FindIndex(c => argsLower.All(x => c == x));
```

Answer (score 0):

A regex-based solution, for the record:

```
private int FindIndexOf(List<string> list, params string[] args)
{
    string pattern = args.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), 
        (sb, a) => sb.Append("(?=.*").Append(Regex.Escape(a)).Append(")")
    ).ToString();
    Regex regEx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return list.FindIndex(s => regEx.IsMatch(s));
}
```