# Linq Contains doesn't work on List

Tags: linq, list, contains

**Items**
Code
A
B
C

```
from x in Items where(x.Code.Contains("a")) select x  //This Linq returns A
```

```
from x in Items.ToList() where(x.Code.Contains("a")) select x //This Linq returns nothing
```

In the second Linq it has become Case Sensitive may i know why and how to overcome this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL server is case-insensitive using the default collation, so either case will work when the SQL query is executed against the database. When you call `ToList()`, all the items are fetched from the database and put in a case sensitive `List<T>`, then the items are filtered. As the `List<T>` is case-sensitive, it will return false for lowercase values.

You should be using the first code you have, as otherwise in the case of a large table you will have performance issues as you will basically be doing a `SELECT * FROM` with the second code.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because your first query is `Linq-To-SQL`, so case insensitive, while your second query is `Linq-To-Objects`, so pure objects with all that comes with it.
Then simply do the following:

```
from x in Items.ToList() where(x.Code.ToLower().Contains("a")) select x
```

It should do the work.

Comment: Does not pass the [turkish-test](http://stackoverflow.com/a/234751/284240) ;)  Is also less efficient than using `IndexOf` with an appropriate `StringComparison`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that this is LINQ-To-SQL or some other LINQ provider that translates it to SQL. The database is case insentitive [by default](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224256%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) but C# is not. When you call `ToList` you create an in-memory list. Since `x.Code` seems to be a `String` you are using `String.Contains` which looks for sub-strings case-sensitive.

You can use `String.IndexOf` with `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` if you want:

```
from x in Items.ToList() 
where(x.Code.IndexOf("a", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0) 
select x
```