# Case insensitive .contains for delegates?

Tags: c#, linq

If I have an array and I'm using LINQ to check the array elements contain a string using .All() is there a way to do this being case insensitive?

My code is:

```
string s1 = "hello my name is blah";
string[] split2 = fund.Split(' ');
if (split2.All((s1.Contains)))
    {
        //Do something
    }
```

If I was doing a simple .Contains(string) I could use the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring). I think the answer will be roughly the same but I'm unsure how to implement the original solution when using delegates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
split2.All(s1.Contains)
```

is effectively a shorthand for

```
split2.All(str => s1.Contains(str))
```

knowing this, it should now be easy for you to apply the extra parameter that you need.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. I like this approach over spoon feeding. +1

Comment: @SriramSakthivel : Yep. ["Give a man a fish"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime) always seems like a better approach to me. It seems some people just want the fish right now!

Comment: I wish I could +1 you once more for the quote :)

Comment: This was the piece of information I was missing thanks.

Comment: You cannot use `Contains` for a case insensitive string comparison. `s1.Contains(str, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)` won't compile if that is what you suggest.

Comment: @TimSchmelter It will, if you include [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/444818/2530848). I believe that's what OP is talking about

Comment: @TimSchmelter : You're right. I'm sure there's enough info here for OP to proceed though.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use a lambda expression instead:

```
if (
     split2.All
     (str => s1.IndexOf(str, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create delegate which wraps Contains

```
Func<string, bool> insensitiveContains = s => s1.Contains(s, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

That you can use insensitiveContains as argument to All():

```
if (split2.All(insensitiveContains))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the overload of [`String.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425(v=vs.110).aspx) which accepts a `StringComparison`:

```
bool containsAll = split2
    .All(s2 => s1.IndexOf(s2, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)>= 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

Spender was right but far short:

```
split2.All(str => s1.ToUpper().Contains(str.ToUpper()))
```

is what you need.

Comment: This wont compile, you should also avoid ToUpper or ToLower to compare case insensitively.http://stackoverflow.com/a/234751/284240 It is also less efficient since it needs to create many temporary strings.

Comment: You are right, Add->All, add () and ) to the code. If performance is a real issue, don't use string at all.

Comment: You can always edit your answer. Performance is not the only thing, there are cultures where you get an unexpected result if you convert a string to  upper-/lowercase.  For example: http://blog.codinghorror.com/whats-wrong-with-turkey/ So it's better to always use  `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` instead. For a sub-string search you have to use `s1.IndexOf(s2, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)>= 0`.

Comment: I didn't see this option. Thx.