# switch case inside linq query

Tags: c#, linq

How can I convert below foreach statement in corresponding linq with possible null handling:

```
foreach (var val in userData.ManagedUsers.Values)
        {
            if (val.UserId == userId)
            {
                foreach (var role in val.Roles)
                {
                    switch (role.ToLower())
                    {
                        case "underwriter1":
                            return "1";
                        case "underwriter2":
                            return "2";
                        case "underwriter3":
                            return "3";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: No reason to downvote. This was a legit question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use this:

```
string result = userData.ManagedUsers.Values
    .Where(u => u.UserId == userId)
    .SelectMany(u => u.Roles)
    .Select(r => {
        if(String.Equals(r, "underwriter1", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            return "1";
        else if(String.Equals(r, "underwriter2", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            return "2";
        else if(String.Equals(r, "underwriter3", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            return "3";
        else return null; 
    }).First(r => r != null);
```

I don't use a `switch` here because you need to use `ToLower` to compare case-insensitively. You don't pass the [turkey test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234591/upper-vs-lower-case) then. Therefore i'm using `String.Equals` with  `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` which is also more efficient and handles the case that `Role` is `null`.

By the way, this seems to be even better if i understand your logic correctly:

```
 string result = userData.ManagedUsers.Values
     .Where(u => u.UserId == userId)
     .SelectMany(u => u.Roles)
     .Select(r => r != null && r.StartsWith("underwriter") ? r.Substring("underwriter".Length) : null)
     .First();
```

Comment: Have you tried this? (Has anyone who upvoted, or OP who accepted?)

Comment: @Rawling: it was difficult to test without the classes or sample data.

Comment: It's not hard to test the "interesting" step with `new string[0]`.

Comment: @Rawling: you're right, i've tested it. The lambda expression needs to return something which was not the case without the `else`. I've fixed it with an exception. I've also added another more concise approach.

Comment: With the exception there, you only ever check the first role.

Comment: @Rawling: i came to the conclusion that your version is the best way ;)

Comment: Heh, we converge eventually. There are probably further improvements we could both make if we both look at "what *should* this code be doing" rather than "how can I replace these loops" but to be honest I can't be bothered.

Answer (score 1):

Since C# 8.0 the following should work:

```
string result = userData.ManagedUsers.Values
.Where(u => u.UserId == userId)
.SelectMany(u => u.Roles)
.Select(r => 
    r.ToLower() switch
    {
       "underwriter1" => "1",
       "underwriter2" => "2",
       "underwriter3" => "3"
    }).First(r => r != null);
```