# String.Contains doesnt work as expected with folders returned by Directory.GetDirectories

Tags: vb.net, foreach

For some reason, this statement completely bypasses folders which contain said text, what am I doing wrong?

```
For Each fold As String In Directory.GetDirectories("C:\documents")
    If fold.Contains("pdf") Then
```

I have folders in the c:\documents folder with names such as:

```
pdfone
pdfretrieve
extrapdf
```

When VS reads through, I see the strings:

```
"c:\documents\pdfone"
"c:\documents\pdfretrieve"
"c:\documents\extrapdf"
```

But it reads right past them and doesn't enter the If statement.

Comment: Are you sure that it isn't `PDFone`?

Comment: Yes, it's PDFone. Is the .Contains property case sensitive?

Comment: This works great here. Are you sure your "fold" contains what you think?

Comment: It's actually PDFone?! You lied in your question! :)

Comment: can also change to `If fold.ToLower().Contains("pdf") Then`, although the answer below is a better approach

Comment: @RianBattle: apart from the fact that this creates unnecessary string garbage in memory it is also prone to localization issues like the [turkish i problem](http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html). So using `ToUpper`/`ToLower` [is not the best approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234591/upper-vs-lower-case) to provide case-insensitivity.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I wasn't aware of that at all, thanks for the info (this is why I like StackOverflow!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Yes, it's PDFone. Is the .Contains property case sensitive?

[`String.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is case-sensitive (like most methods in the .NET framework). You have to use [`String.IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want to ignore the case:

```
If fold.IndexOf("pdf", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnorecase) >= 0 Then
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) mentions it here:

> this method performs an ordinal (**case-sensitive and
>   culture-insensitive**) comparison. The search begins at the first
>   character position of this string and continues through the last
>   character position.

As an aside, `GetDirectories` returns the directory-name including their paths. So searching for substrings on the complete path is error-prone. Instead you could use [`Path.GetFileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)(yes, not [`GetDirectoryName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname(v=vs.110).aspx) since that returns the parent directory, that's mentioned in the *remarks*):

```
If Path.GetFileName(fold).IndexOf("pdf", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnorecase) >= 0 Then
```

Comment: New to vb.net here and still getting used to case sensitivity. Thanks!

Comment: @Gmac: you're welcome. Note that i've edited my answer to show a better approach.