# Why ToUpper is faster than ToLower?

Tags: c#, .net

```
Stopwatch stopwatch1 = new Stopwatch();
Stopwatch stopwatch2 = new Stopwatch();
string l = "my test";
string u = "MY TEST";

for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{
    l += l;
    u += u;
}

stopwatch1.Start();
l=l.ToUpper();
stopwatch1.Stop();

stopwatch2.Start();
u=u.ToLower();
stopwatch2.Stop();

// Write result.
Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: \nUPPER :  {0}\n LOWER : {1}",
                  stopwatch1.Elapsed, stopwatch2.Elapsed);
```

I have run many times:

```
UPPER : 00:00:01.3386287
LOWER : 00:00:01.4546552

UPPER : 00:00:01.1614189
LOWER : 00:00:01.1970368

UPPER : 00:00:01.2697430
LOWER : 00:00:01.3460950

UPPER : 00:00:01.2256813
LOWER : 00:00:01.3075738
```

Comment: in the first instance, you should time more than one conversion! try like 10000

Comment: and try reversing the order to eliminate caching effects

Comment: You should use ToUpperInvariant and ToLowerInvariant. And you use BenchmarkDotNet to do tests.

Comment: [Upper vs Lower Case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234591/upper-vs-lower-case),

Comment: [This might be the answer you are looking for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c#12137). "When normalizing strings, it is highly recommended that you use ToUpperInvariant instead of ToLowerInvariant **because Microsoft has optimized the code for performing uppercase comparisons**."

Comment: @SenJacob reverse the operations and you'll see that the first one is still the fastest. Timings of single calls have no meaning

Comment: I've reopened the question since actually `ToUpper` *is not* faster than `ToLower`, at least on the data provided.

Comment: if  Microsoft has optimized the code for performing uppercase comparisons
is it because the ASCII code for uppercase letters only two digits 65 - 90
while ASCII code Lowercase letters 97 -122 which contains 3 digits (need more processing)

Comment: Why do you think it needs more processing? It are still the same bytes, right?

Comment: @SenJacob: Your comment is refering to `ToUpperInvariant`. That is a small but very important difference. The invariant conversion is not the same as the culture-specific conversion of `ToUpper`. I would also dispute the optimization towards `ToUpperInvariant` as compared to `ToLowerInvariant`. That is basically a difference between performing a `+` and a `-`. Unless your source makes a compelling argument towards such a claim, I would doubt its correctness.

Answer (score 6):

Let's try *reproducing* the result

```
  // Please, notice: the same string for both ToUpper/ToLower
  string GiniPig = string.Concat(Enumerable
    .Range(1, 1000000) // a million chunks "my test/MyTest" combined (long string)
    .Select(item => "my test/MY TEST"));

   Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

   // Let's try n (100) times - not just once
   int n = 100;

   var sampling = Enumerable
     .Range(1, n)
     .Select(x => {
        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();

        GiniPig.ToLower(); // change this into .ToUpper();

        sw.Stop();
        return sw.ElapsedMilliseconds; })
     .ToSampling(x => x); // Side library; by you may save the data and analyze it with R

   Console.Write(
     $"N = {n}; mean = {sampling.Mean:F0}; std err = {sampling.StandardDeviation:F0}");
```

Having run several times (warming) I've got the results (Core i7 3.6 GHz, .Net 4.6 IA-64):

```
ToLower: N = 100; mean = 38; std err = 8
ToUpper: N = 100; mean = 37; std err = 9
```

So you *can't reject* the null hypothesis that `ToLower` is as faster as `ToUpper` and thus your experiment has got *errors*:

1. You have *different* strings to process
2. Processing *short* (`175` characters only) string just once (not in a loop) should be instant and thus the errors can be enourmous
3. You have to *warm up* the routine (in order methods to be compiled, assemblies loaded, caches filled up etc.)

It seems (the time elapsed is more than 1 second for a very easy operation) it's rule #3 (warming up) breakage which ruined the experiment

Comment: as people comment " Microsoft has optimized the code for performing uppercase comparisons ."
Is it because the ASCII code for uppercase letters only two digits 65 - 90 while ASCII code Lowercase letters 97 -122 which contains 3 digits (need more processing)?

Comment: @Medo Medo: both `65` and `122` are ether *single* `char` or *single* `byte`; that's why the time (in your example) will be the same (CPU doesn't operate with *digits*, but with `byte`s `int`s `long`s etc. )

Comment: When you reproduce the result, are you sure you are on the same culture as the OP? Check my reply.

Comment: @Sefe: The experiment has been carried out on pure *Ascii* text; so culture should not be the case. If only the text contained culture specific letters (say a string partially on Russian, partially on Georgian and on Chinese) the culture could have been the key feaure, and it might have been ocurred that in such conditions `ToUpper` is faster/slower than `ToLower`

Comment: Well, the logic of converting characters from one case to another is at least partially being executed by culture-specific code. Regardless of the input values, there can be differences in the respective implementation that case different performance.

Comment: @Sefe: I've tried the same experiment for the cultures `"en-US"`, `"de-De"` (German), `"ka-Ge"` (Georgian), `"ru-Ru"` (Russian) I've got the same results mean `38` with `9` standard error

Answer (score 3):

Your intial hypothesis of `ToUpper` being faster than `ToLower` has a logical fallacy.

Your conversions are **culture-sensitive**. You are not performing an ordinal operation, you are performing an operation dependent on your current culture (as returned by `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`). A conversion from lower case to upper case *might* be faster in the culture that you are using and it *might* be slower in another. A conversion in one culture *might* be also faster than a conversion in another culture.

So your initial assumtion that there is **one** performance for `ToUpper` and `ToLower`is false.

Comment: Yes, the experiment to be properly carried out should specify culture; Something like "why `ToUpper(new CultureInfo("ka-Ge"))` significally `faster then ToLower(new CultureInfo("ka-Ge"))` ... ". And there're two possible anwers (for the culture specified):  "...because Microsoft has optimized the code for performing uppercase comparisons..." and "this is culture specific behaviour"