# .Any() not working as expected when letter case involved

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a very simple Linq-to-SQL query that returns a boolean:

```
using (MyDataContext TheDC = new MyModelDataContext())
{
    return !TheDC.SomeTable.Any(l => l.UserID == SomeLong && l.ColumnName == SomeString);
}
```

The problem is that when the comparison involves strings that differ by the case of some letters, it returns false. For instance, if the table contains `testString` and SomeString is `TestString`, it returns false.

How can I rewrite it?

Comment: Well. Wouldn't this be a collation issue on the database?

Comment: whats your db's COLLATE

Comment: Try `l.ColumnName.ToLower() == SomeString.ToLower()`

Comment: ...so information missing is the type of database and the collation of column being queried.

Comment: @BanForFun ...and lose the benefit of any indexes on that column.

Comment: @spender some databases, like postegresql, allow to define index on functions (so index on 'lower(ColumnName)'),  so it's not that clear.

Comment: @Steve: it's set at the DB level to SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: @Evk IIRC linq2sql only works on SQL server, so in the absence of more info, that's my assumption.

Comment: @frenchie That's a case-insensitive, accent-sensitive collation, so no lead so far. Anything on the column? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/view-collation-information

Comment: For the specific column, it's set at database default

Comment: You're probably going to have to come up with a reproducible test case to move this forward any further... :(

Comment: ToLower can not pass the turkey test, be carefull about that. https://stackoverflow.com/a/234751/3580273

Comment: Funny that 100 times upvoted accepted answer in duplicate question does not actually answers at all, since doesn't work with linq to sql (as I understand).

Comment: Indeed, the answer linked as a duplicate doesn't work at all

Comment: Well anyway, I found a work around that doesn't require this anymore.

Answer (score -1):

You have the [Equal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/how-to-compare-strings) funcion

in your case it's should look like this:

```
using (MyDataContext TheDC = new MyModelDataContext())
{
    return !TheDC.SomeTable.Any(l => l.UserID == SomeLong && l.ColumnNameEquals(SomeString, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
}
```

Comment: This is just a variation on the other **strongly** downvoted answers, and probably doesn't make it through the linq2sql translation to SQL. Are you sure you want to post this?

Comment: @spender Unlike other answers this simply doesn't do a case insensitive comparison.  LINQ to sql knows how to interpret this code, it just ignores the comparison operator and uses the DB's collation settings regardless.  So this answer is actually bad for very different reasons than the other answers.

Comment: i'm pretty sure it's the best answer to this weird case.
btw, this question marked as duplicated, i recommend you to watch the answer over there :)

Comment: @TomMendelson Why do you think an answer that doesn't actually work is the best answer?

Answer (score -4):

Would you like to try this code?

```
using (MyDataContext TheDC = new MyModelDataContext())
{
    return !TheDC.SomeTable.Any(l => l.UserID == SomeLong && l.ColumnName.ToLower() == SomeString.ToLower());
}
```

Comment: an awesome way to destroy index

Comment: wow. Of course, if you think about performance, index or full text search should be considered. And it is not copied. The answer was only slow.

Comment: index/full text search will get destroyed completely if you are doing .ToLower().

Comment: I agree with your answer.
I just thought that the questioner would have asked the C# code rather than the DB.

Comment: I think the answer to this question about performance may be an over-answer to the question.
Of course, simple answer is to add a lower-cased column to the DB.

Answer (score -4):

I'd try, tolower() and for good measure check the db collate.

```
l.ColumnName.ToLower() == SomeString.ToLower()
```

Comment: Check the other answer and act quickly...

Comment: Really? Is everyone copying my comment?

Comment: No,  just you posted faster

Comment: Yeah, but they should see the comments (and the already existing answer) before they do the exact same

Comment: pretty sure someone with 18k rep would have known this method. But he has a very valid reason not to do it: Index